# How to remove automatic column gap for grid items inside grid container?

Tags: css, css-grid

I’m having trouble with my grid container, I’m trying to adjust the grid gap, it seems that my grid column gap is being set automatically, how do I fix that? And why is that happening?

I’ve even tried using a negative value like “grid-column-gap: -50px” to see if it would adjust/close the column gap but it didn’t. Could anyone take a look and help? Thanks

My HTML:

```
<div class="gallery-grid">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Hay Bales">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="Lake">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" alt="Canyon">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/04.jpg" alt="Iceberg">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/05.jpg" alt="Desert">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/06.jpg" alt="Fall">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/07.jpg" alt="Plantation">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/08.jpg" alt="Dunes">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/09.jpg" alt="Countryside Lane">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/10.jpg" alt="Sunset">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/11.jpg" alt="Cave">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/12.jpg" alt="Bluebells">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gallery-grid {
    max-width: 1000px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
    grid-row-gap: 2rem;
    margin: 45px auto;
}
```

what it currently looks like:
[image: what it currently looks like:]

what I'm aiming for:
[image]

Comment: `repeat(auto-fit, 250px)` ?

Comment: or `img{width:100%}` ?

Comment: This is a job for flexbox not CSS-Grid

Answer (score 0):

hfor you :

```css
.gallery-grid {
/*     max-width: 1000px;

    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
    grid-row-gap: 2rem;*/
    margin: 45px ; 
   display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:  repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows:1fr;
  gap:2rem;
}
img{
/*   width: 200px; */
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-grid">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Hay Bales">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="Lake">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" alt="Canyon">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/04.jpg" alt="Iceberg">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/05.jpg" alt="Desert">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/06.jpg" alt="Fall">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/07.jpg" alt="Plantation">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/08.jpg" alt="Dunes">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/09.jpg" alt="Countryside Lane">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/10.jpg" alt="Sunset">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/11.jpg" alt="Cave">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/12.jpg" alt="Bluebells">
</div>
```